# Objective-C using block when get list file using Google Driver API

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I am using the Google Drive API. When I use the demo to get the file list I think this app run multi thread. Now I want get file list when method succeeds.

```
- (void)fetchFiles {
    self.output.text = @"Getting files...";
    GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
    //query.pageSize = 10; /* Total number of files to get at once But useful only when there are more than hundreds of file to get once.*/
    query.fields = @"nextPageToken, files(id, name)";
    [self.service executeQuery:query delegate:self didFinishSelector:@selector(displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:)];
}
```

link : https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can try it.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^blockHandler)(id data);
```

```
// get list file
- (void)listFiles:(NSString *)fileId complete:(void(^)(id data))completion {
self.blockHandler = completion;

GTLRDriveQuery_FilesList *query = [GTLRDriveQuery_FilesList query];
query.fields = @"nextPageToken, files(id, name, thumbnailLink, webViewLink)";
query.pageSize = 1000;
query.q = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@' In parents and trashed=false",fileId];

[self.service executeQuery:query
                  delegate:self
         didFinishSelector:@selector(displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:)];
}

- (void)displayResultWithTicket:(GTLRServiceTicket *)ticket
         finishedWithObject:(GTLRDrive_FileList *)result
                      error:(NSError *)error {
if (error == nil) {
    NSMutableString *output = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    if (result.files.count > 0) {
        [output appendString:@"Files:\n"];
        for (GTLRDrive_File *file in result.files) {
            itemGG *temp = [[itemGG alloc] initWithName:file.name linkThumb:file.thumbnailLink fileID:file.identifier];
            [self.lstItem addObject:temp];
            [output appendFormat:@"%@ (%@)\n", file.name, file.identifier];
        }
    } else {
        [output appendString:@"No files found."];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", output);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error getting presentation data: %@\n", error.localizedDescription);
}

if (self.blockHandler) {
    self.blockHandler([[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:self.lstItem]);
}
}
```

```
__weak typeof(self) w = self;
[self.cloud listFiles:@"root" complete:^(id data) {
    w.tableData = data;
    [w.myCollection reloadData];
}];
```